# Old Server 2019 Domain Controller Completely Crashed

Tags: domain, controller

We had a Windows Server STD 2019 and it took a lightning strike and destroyed Hard Drive VM data
Could not recover.

New Setup in place with Exact Same Server OS. The exact Same Domain Controller Name.
Rebuilt Active User Directory on New Server.  NO VM just installed Server STD 2019 OS Directly to SSD Drive for easier Recovery and Backup in the Future

The Issue now: I Need to get all Client Computers signed into New Domain Controller. Need to know the Best way to go about this?

Comment: “Is there any Software available to do this or assist with this? “ - There isn’t but questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope. Furthermore, your clients are not aware the DC failed. So you have to join those clients to what’s essentially a new domain. Proper and complete backups would have prevented the need to do that.

Comment: It's called starting over.

Answer (score 0):

If no backup is available you need to re-create all users, re-join all domain members, re-do all groups. Users will be fresh on all machines, so you'll need to migrate their local data.

You should make sure you have a reliable backup in the future.

Comment: The original Admin set the DC up in a VM.  The VM data Corrupted and we do have a AOMEI Backup of the data but it will not restore due to a Path error.  We recreated the New DC Exactly like the Old on including the same IP of Old Server.  Still cannot get AOMEI Cyber Backup to Restore.  We are in touch with them and they are reviewing 'Logs'.  The issue is I cannot sign out the Users to their Local accounts as we do not have PW from Old Admin and any changes you want to make requires the old DC to be in place so it is a HUGE problem.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to move the Profile if possible.  Which would save a LOT of time redeploying

Comment: @psccomputers i suggest, that you open a Ticket on AOMEI (Whatever unknown company that is beyond) and tell them about the citicallity. using veeam would mostly having a SLA in less then 2H - why not restoring the original data to the origianl path - a VM is nothing else from outside of view, e peace of a configuration file and the data files itself - it can be imported usually. and aslong as 30 days have not passed, you can even use an older restore point (as said it is not allowed beeing older as 30 days)